# thin: waiting for n connection to close while trying to stop server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, production-environment, thin

I have put my application (Ruby on Rails) on (Ubuntu) Amazon EC2 server which is running on thin and nginx.
Whenever I stop my thin production server I am getting this message as "waiting for n connection(s) to finish,can take up to 30 sec, **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** to stop"

Below is the attached screenshot.....

[image: Image on server]

What does it mean and why is it coming.I had to wait for a long time for the connections to stop.I have Thin version 1.5.1.
And since this is Live environment We don't want the website to go down for much time.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just set 'wait' to need seconds in thin.yml!