# rails: is there any need to delete session variable (cookie based session store)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session-variables, session-cookies

I am creating session variable in rails using `session[:name]="sanjay"`. I have done some research and came to know that session variables in rails are stored as a cookie on client side.so i just want to know that is there any need to delete session variable in cookie based session store.are sessions deleted automatically In server side when client  closed the browser??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to clean up session variables.  While I don't think they are automatically deleted on browser terminate they are indeed cleaned up by the browser eventually (expiry dates)

Comment: @ilan-berci - if i dont delete the session variable,will it give an issue..(like memory full error).since when i stoped my thin server i am getting warning message as "waiting for n connection(s) to finish,can take up to 30 sec, CTRL+C to stop".is this because of session variables are not deleted on my server.I have posted this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006268/thin-waiting-for-n-connection-to-close-while-trying-to-stop-server

Comment: @mdesantis : do you have any idea about the above.

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe frankly no, I have never encountered this issue. It doesn't make sense to me that you have to delete the session variables. Did you try using another application server (f.e. Unicorn)?